# VB6 Excel.Application Object "Permission Denied"

Tags: vb6, excel, vba

> > I am giving up, will send everything to an XLS VBA. Thanks!

I am having to add a small modification to a VB6 program on a Win7 and Office2010 (v14.0 32bits) environment.
Currently the program tries to instantiate by the following line of code:

```
Dim objExcel as Excel.Application
Set objExcel = New Excel.Application
```

Right after executing the 2nd line of code, I am showed the error 70: Permission Denied.
I have tried a simple test on an Excel VBA, for the same line of code, and works great.

Any clues? is it possible that a service that should be running is down?
Anything I should do to avoid reinstalling Office?

Hints I have collected:

1. Have tried to config permissions on DCOMCNFG but wasn't able to find the Excel Application.
2. Have tried to run excel.exe /regserver but nothing to seems to happen: Excel runs as usual when it is supposed to run silently.
3. Ran ProcessMonitor and found that a call to `Excel.exe \automation` showed `Path Not Found` (I have checked the path, is ok, I guess the `\automation` is bothering around).
4. If I change the code to instantiate a Word Application (and of course dll references), same error appears.
5. Full permissions given to Office14 folder. Img in follwing link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sgZW5.png
   (Sorry, as new user, can't post images)

Thanks in advance.

Gabriel

Comment: Have you tried right click on Excel and 'run as administrator'?

Comment: Yes, I have just did: 
1) Launched Excel as Admin, 
2) Launched VB6 as Admin,
Error appears.

Comment: Can you share the code where you are declaring the excel objects and finally initializing them?

Comment: Are you the administrator on this pc?

Comment: Ok. 1 quick question. Is your MS Office 32bit or 64 bit?

Comment: @SidharthRout > v14 32bits. Thx.

Comment: I cannot be sure, but have you tried `CreateObject("Excel.Application")` instead of the `New` keyword?

Comment: @ja72 > Yes. `Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")` same thing happens.

Comment: You could not find Excel in DCOMCNFG ? Now something's bad... If it's not there (and if I'm not mistaken), you can't create your Excel object, since it needs COM access. Double-check in Console Root > Component Services > Computers > My Computer > DCOM Configuration > Microsft Excel Application. It should definitively be there...

Comment: @t-fabre > I don't have that. Indeed, I don't have any Microsoft App. That makes me think I should reinstall Office, right?. But, how is it possible that the same code does works from a VBA Excel module? Thanks!

Comment: Well, you could always reinstall Office as you said, or try Bob Riemersma suggestion. Also try to create another COM object, like WScript.Shell via CreateObject and see if that works...

Comment: Oops I missed your question. Though it needs be to be confirmed, one possible reason that it works from Excel is that Excel doesn't need DCOM to create a new application instance... while VB6 does.

Comment: @T-Fabre > Thx for yor answer... I will try Bob's suggestion and also will try a short VBScript to see what happens. Cheers!

Comment: To all: Reinstalled Office fully. Nothing happened. DCOM Components didn't appear. I still need to try about VB Script. Let you know. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I have facing similar problem, I am using in my access DB VBA for opening excel files and therefore I am using command "Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")", which suddenly one day starts to throw error 70 Access denied and before it worked fine for couple of months. I start to google it and the moment I learned that it is DCOM error I realized the source of the problems. Because few days ago I was trying to connect my PC with OPC client installed to OPC server and it required to change my local default DCOM setting, I needed to change the default authentification level. So the resolution of my problem was:

1. run command dcomcnfg in command line
2. go to Console root > Component Services > Computers > My Computer > DCOM config > Microsof Excel Application
3. right clic and select properties
4. In the general tab change the Authentification Level to "None"

and tats it

Answer (score 1):

Try this

1) Open Windows Explorer and navigate to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office`

3) Right click on the folder "Office14" and click on "Properties"

4) Navigate to the "Security" Tab

5) Give "Full Control" to [Machine]\Users.

6) Now Try running your vb6 App again

[image]

Comment: Can you post a snapshot of your security tab for Office 14 folder?

Comment: BTW are you the only person using this computer?

Comment: > Yes, I am the only person on this computer. Post updated with the snapshot. Ths.

Comment: Ok. i cant see the snapshot yet. Do this for testing purpose. Repeat the same step with `C:\Windows\System32` folder and with `VB6` folder

Comment: My user has fullcontrol over both directories. VB6 is being run as administrator.

Comment: great. Now one last thing. Confirm if "administrator" also has full control on all 3 folders

Comment: Yes, confirmed, full control on both 3 folders.

Comment: If all 3 folders have full control and the rights have also been passed to the subfolder and files then the program should work. Let me install vb6 and check.

Comment: Hold on, before installing vb6. I think the problem is in the Office installation as I don't see any DCOM component from MSO. I will reinstall.

Comment: Reinstalled Office fully. Nothing happened. DCOM Components didn't appear. I still need to try about VB Script. Let you know. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It just struck me : from your screenshots, it seems you are running Office 32 bits on a 64bits Windows.

So by default, when you open up DCOMCNFG.exe, you access the 64bits version. Which allows you to edit 64bits COM components. And explains why you can't find Excel in there, since Excel is running in WoW64.

You should try the following command :

```
C:\Windows\System32\mmc.exe comexp.msc /32
```

To open the 32bits console. From there you should find settings for Excel's COM component, and edit its permissions. Allow access to everyone, and try running your program again. If that works, you shouldfine tune your permissions afterwords to allow only specific users (allowing DCOM access to everyone IS dangerous...).

Hope that helps.

Comment: Wow !! Good deduction !! I have found the component reviewed the permissions but didn't worked. Nevertheless, I have tried the VBS and worked great (coudln't replicate on VB6). I will review VB6 installation, review a procmon snapshot and let you know.

Comment: Truth be told, I had the same problem a while back... so your problem was oddly familiar, but it took me some time to remember. Did you try giving permissions to All users and Unauthenticated users ?

Comment: Also under the Identity tab, check which user the DCOM component is running as... Another thing is that VB6 *might* be looking in the "classic" Program Files directory, instead of the Program Files (x86) directory. I had that issue with some old (~Win98/Win2K programs) installed on Win7, that were looking in the wrong folder.

Comment: I have checked the references in the project, and they are pointing to the right dll (Excel.exe in this case). I have also added everyone, and nothgin happens. I just don't know. I am giving up, will send everything to an XLS VBA. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In DCOM CONFIG try setting the following:

1. General Tab -> Authentication Level -> None
2. Identity Tab -> select 'the interactive user'

hope this helps

Comment: Dude, you're a life saver! :)

Comment: did both steps, but still, the 'permission denied' error sticked like gum to a shoe's sole. what did the trick was to set the 'launch and activation permissions' in the  security tab (in the properties of the Microsoft.Excel component in the DCOM CONFIG). there you should choose 'Customize' and press 'Edit'. in the customization screen add the user that initiated the process. in my case it was - otorita-web01/users. and give it local permissions to launch and activate the component.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked your DCOM *default* security settings on the machine?  These are in the Properties of "My Computer" in the Component Services MMC snap-in.  You can still get there by running `dcomcnfg`.

Comment: I have and didn't find anything that would capture my attention. Any special parameter I should focus on? Thx